# moderncv - non marvosym symbols

Tags: symbols, moderncv

When i use the `moderncv` package i get the typical `marvosym` symbols.

The following image shows the file `examples\template_banking_red.pdf` that comes with my moderncv package. When you take a look at the `template_banking_red.pdf` from [this host](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template_banking_red.pdf) it features different symbols for mobile/phone/mail and also additional github/linkedin/twitter symbols. I just updated my texlive yet i still obtain the old symbols.

What do i have to change in `moderncv` to obtain the latter result?

[image]

Comment: Please note that in order to use the awesome font icon set, you need to run Xe(La)TeX or Lua(La)TeX

Comment: where is the `.tex` file for that example?  all i can find is the `.pdf`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is the default behavior since version 1.5.0 for the `casual` style variant (the one you pictured), released today. It is using the [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) package as stated in another answer, and will load it automatically.

FYI, the new version of moderncv introduces a way to switch between icon sets, i.e.

```
\moderncvicons{<icon set>}
```

where `<icon set>` can be `awesome` (the one you wants), `marvosym` (the old ones) or `letters` (letter icons, used by default in the `oldstyle` style variant).

Unfortunately, TeX Live 2012 is frozen right now and TeX Live 2013 will only be released on July 1st. So if you want the icons above, you will need to download the newest version of [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) manually ([`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) should already be installed on your system, as it was released before the freeze).

Comment: When will you provide a documentation? You class is very popular (I use it too) but the missing documentation is really a disadvantages. Please note: I like your class and it's really useful.

Comment: After the last release with new features, it's now next on my todo list, together with solving incompatibility with `biblatex` :)

Comment: Sorry to interrupt, I'm having problems compiling a resume with pdflatex. Log file says it can't find `moderncviconsawsome.sty` even though it is present inside _/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/_ folder. I'm using Mageia 2 and TeXLive

Comment: I'm having the same problem of @WobbyWindows, this is the output `ls` on my _/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/moderncv/_ folder: `moderncv.cls  moderncvcompatibility.sty  moderncvthemecasual.sty  moderncvthemeclassic.sty  moderncvthemeempty.sty`, no _moderncviconsawsome.sty_ inside. I have the latest version (1.5.1) installed with texlive.

Comment: I solved my problem in Windows by compiling the `cv.tex` file with XeTeX instead of pdfLaTeX. I haven't tried in Linux so far, maybe it'll work...who knows!

Comment: @Xavier, do you know any font for Instagram symbol?

Comment: @Sigur If you use a recent (>= 4.3.0) version of `fontawesome`, you can use `\faInstagram` or `\faicon{instagram}` to get [this](http://fontawesome.io/icon/instagram/).

Answer (score 13):

This style loads the great new font package [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome) and uses te defined symbols there.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\faTwitter

\faLinkedin

\faGithub

\faLinkedinSign
\end{document}
```