# How to use fontawesome-package in moderncv?

Tags: moderncv, fontawesome

since I am working on my CV using moderncv, I was wondering if it is possible to change the icons used in the header. These icons are from the package marvosym. As indicated by this question [moderncv - non marvosym symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110342/moderncv-non-marvosym-symbols), you can use the fontawesome-package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\faTwitter

\faLinkedin

\faLinkedinSign
\end{document}
```

Seems to be easy, but unfortunately I receive an error message even if I compile with xelatex or lualatex. The error indicates the following:

```
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
!
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
!
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
```

Both xelatex and lualatex are functioning well with other codes. Hence, I do not know what's the problem. However, I would really like to use the icons from the fontawesome-package.

Does anybody has an idea?

Thank you very much in advance,

Phil

Comment: Does the use of LuaTex or XeTeX cause any trouble with the fontawesome package? It seems that it load the fontspec package and you need to compile with one of the two

Comment: It is clearly stated in the `fontawesome` documentation that you need to run `XeLateX` or `LuaLaTeX`. The error message you receive says that you are using pdftex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Romain Picot. Neither with the fontawesome nor the fontspec package it works. Further, the error message remains the same in both cases.

Comment: nd btw: What does that have to do with moderncv?

Comment: It looks like that you have a hidden first line in your document, something like `%! pdflatex`, which tells the editor that it should always run `pdflatex`. Look for sucha line and delete it. With current TeXLive 2014 your example works very well with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

Comment: @Herbert: I am using Texmaker. Checking the settings, I found _pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex_ for `pdflatex`. I guess that's what you have referred to in your comment. Do you know what would be the right command to be able to use `xelatex` or `lualatex` without problems?

Comment: in TeXmaker simply use `xelatex` from the compiler list or instead of `Quick Build` in this screenshot http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/texmakertop_big.png

Comment: @Herbert: that's exactly what I am doing, however, I get the error mentioned above. Maybe you could give me any other advice?

Comment: Send me your example: hvoss@tug.org I cannot believe that you run it with `xelatex`

Answer (score 14):

My example:

```
\documentclass{moderncv}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\firstname{H}\lastname{foo}    
\begin{document}
\faTwitter

\faLinkedin

\faLinkedinSign
\end{document}
```

run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

[image]

The otf version of FontAwesome is saved in the TeXLive path which is by default not searched by `xetex`. `luatex` uses its own font handling and will find the file. One can test it:

```
voss@shania:~> fc-list | grep fontawesome
/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/fontawesome/FontAwesome.otf: FontAwesome:style=Regular
```

if there is no output then `xelatex` will not find the font. In a file `~/fontconfig/fonts.conf` I have

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
 <dir>/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
 <dir>/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
 <dir>/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
 <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/opentype</dir>
 <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/truetype</dir>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">
   <const>none</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hinting">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="hintstyle">
   <const>hintmedium</const>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match target="font">
  <edit mode="assign" name="antialias">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <dir>~/.fonts</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

which tells `fontconfig` also to search for fonts in `/usr/local/texlive/current/...` . `current` is always a link which points to the current TL version. After creating that file run `fc-cache -fv`.

Test your file with `lualatex`, it should generate the font list by default if it
doesn't find awesome. Or run `luaotfload-tool --update --force` before testinmg it with `lualatex`

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. However, I do not get what I should do. Are these commands for LaTeX? Probably I am simply too stupid... Is there  no easy way to use the fontawesome package?

Comment: copy the abobe example into a new document of TeXmaker. Then run it with `xelatex`. If there is an error then have a look into the settings of your commands.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I do not get any error. Maybe it is important to know that I used as documentclass article. What should I do next?

Comment: If you had no error then you had a pdf output, right?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but yes, i had a pdf output.

Comment: Ans was it ok or not???

Comment: Well, it looks as follows, don't know if this output is what I should receive:

_<?xml version='1.0'?> <!DOCTYPE fontcong SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'> <font-
cong> <dir>/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir> <dir>/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-
dist/fonts/truetype</dir> <dir>/usr/local/texlive/current/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
<dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/opentype</dir> <dir>/usr/local/texlive/texmf-
local/fonts/truetype</dir> <match target="font"> <edit mode="assign" name="rgba">_

That's a part of the output.

Comment: Oh, that is completely wrong. Read carefully what I wrote. That should be saved in a file named `fonts.conf`.

Comment: @Herbert I include this command in fontawesome.sty \expandafter\def\csname faicon@icon-skype\endcsname         {\symbol{"F17E}}  \def\faSkype             {{\FA\csname faicon@icon-skype\endcsname}}.  But \faSkype is not working properly just showing the empty box.

Answer (score 3):

Just to share my own experience on OSX El Capitan, Herbert's answer almost solved my problem. See also these relevant posts:

- These two posts are very similar to Herbert's: [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/247733/26497), [two](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/257242/26497)
- This [archive](https://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2016-August/039242.html) is relevant to this problem

Here is what ran without error in my case:

- Copy Herbert's XML file to `~/.fonts.conf` (and not `~/fontconfig/fonts.conf` as suggested);
- Run `fc-cache -fv` (takes a while);
- Compile Herbert's example document using `lualatex` (takes a while);
- If you are using `latexmk`, you can set the flag `-pdflatex=lualatex` to use LuaLaTeX instead.

If you need the more recent upgrades of the packages though (with newer symbols), this is not sufficient. In my case, the version of TexLive installed was 2015, and I had to install the latest version (2017) from scratch instead. You can find the installer [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).

Comment: Thanks for putting links to other answers, saved me a bunch of time. This is useful for macOS users.

Comment: For more workarounds, I posted an alternative solution for macOS users at the bottom of: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132888/fontawesome-font-not-found/586014#586014