# moderncv fontawesome

Tags: moderncv, fontawesome

I'm trying to customize my CV using `moderncv` within ShareLaTeX. I wanna use `fontawesome` in the personal details section, but I'm not able yet.

I've found a previous discussion at [moderncv - non marvosym symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110342/moderncv-non-marvosym-symbols), but it was not useful..

Anyone can help me please?

The link to ShareLaTeX is

[sharelatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/552bcb4d87fe31cd2f435187)

BTW: 
I've tried both XeLaLaTeX and LuaLaTeX with the same result: nothing happened!

---

MWE (addition by HK)

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{banking}                            % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{grey}                                % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'

% character encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

% personal data
\name{First}{Last}
%\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{Address}{City}{Country}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
\phone[mobile]{+xx~(xxx)~xxx~xxxx}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{xxx}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{it.linkedin.com/in/xxx/}                         % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                          % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since I'm using the code already written in ShareLaTeX, I guess that the lines that need re-writing are these:

Comment: \RequirePackage{collection}
\collectionnew{phones}
\newcommand*{\phone}[2][fixed]{\collectionadd[#1]{phones}{#2}}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}

% defines one's home page (optional)
% usage: \homepage{<url>}

\newcommand*{\homepage}[1]{\def\@homepage{#1}}

% defines additional personal information (optional)
% usage: \extrainfo{<text>}
\newcommand*{\extrainfo}[1]{\def\@extrainfo{#1}}

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm new to this blog and I don't even know how to post correctly the code... :-( Sorry

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: No problem. Atleast you can provide a link to your sharelatex file, if you don't mind.

Comment: Sure, just a sec. Thanks also for the guide!ù

Comment: I get this  [with xelatex](http://i.stack.imgur.com/MXYIx.png) and [with pdflatex](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uD6su.png)  just for a comparison. So I can't really reproduce the issue.

Comment: The former is what i was looking for! The only difference is that for LinkedIn i want the LinkedIn logo

Comment: Can u please tell me how did u got the former result? Or just modify the code within ShareLaTeX.. Thanks!

Comment: I compiled the code in your question with xelatex to get the first image. thats all.

Comment: Ok, that's exactly my problem.. Compiling that code with xelatex I get the second image, as using lulatex.. Thanks anyway..

Comment: To have a linkedin icon, replace `\homepage{it.linkedin.com/in/xxx/}` with `\social[linkedin]{it.linkedin.com/in/xxx/}`.